# How to delete cell content while keeping the formula in google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

How to delete cell content while keeping the formula in google sheet? Basically I want to reset it's value to blank.
The formula is below
=IF(AND(NOT(ISBLANK(O3)), O3<>"0"), O3, "")

I looked for a Clear Content option in Google sheet but didn't find any.